# Проблемы с dbus, polkit и Network Manager CentOS 7

Tags: centos, vps, centos7, dbus

Не работает сервер. При запуске vps не работает dbus
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все время пытается запуститься, но не успешно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вводе systemctl можно увидеть ошибки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки dbus в журнале(очень много раз пытается запустить dbus)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки начались после того как сервер неожиданно выключился. После этого взаимодействовать с ним можно только через консоль.
Писал в техподдержку хостинга, бесполезно.

Искал информацию про ошибки с работой dbus, polkit и Network Manager, но к решению проблемы так и не пришел.

Возможно ли решить проблему без переустановки?

Comment: Если службы не могут запуститься из-за упавшего dbus, то читайте логи dbus

Comment: @andreymal а какой командой можно вывести их?

Comment: `journalctl -b -u dbus`

Comment: @andreymal добавил отчет этой команды. поиски по ошибки не дали результата. не знаете как эту ошибку можно исправить или в каком направлении думать?

Comment: Блин, я так и боялся, что правый край экрана обрежет половину текста ошибки. Сделайте тогда `journalctl -b -u dbus | less` чтобы убрать горизонтальную прокрутку

Comment: @andreymal добавил вывод вашей команды

Comment: Файл `/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf` должен существовать всегда, он является неотъемлемой частью системы и пакета dbus в частности. Раз его по какой-то причине не оказалось, то в принципе можно считать, что система убита. Теоретически наверно можно попробовать вручную скачать пакет dbus и вручную распаковать оттуда файл в нужное место, однако сам факт отсутствия этого файла намекает на то, что, возможно, отсутствуют и какие-нибудь другие системные файлы, из-за чего может оказаться проще переустановить нахрен всё совсем